# Android - Last screen lock time

Tags: android, screen-lock

Is there a way to find the last time or the time spent since the user locked/unlocked the screen? Is there any log which stores this information?

I am trying to track user (in)activity and looking for the simplest possible way to do it. I know it can be done by continuous tracking through a service perhaps, but was trying to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this cannot be done.

I ended up creating a new service which track the last screen lock/unlock and save the time myself.